# Chromium downloads not working in GNOME Arch

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, chrome

I recently installed Arch Linux with GNOME 42.0. Downloads fail to start in both Google Chrome and Chromium. However, downloads do work in the default GNOME Web browser as well as Mozilla Firefox.

Upon trying to start a download (or simply saving a page using Ctrl + S), the page briefly darkens and then returns to normal. The directory selection popup does not even open, so I cannot select a directory to save the file to. In addition, chrome://downloads is empty.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. This Reddit post, [Gnome 42 save as dialog box not appearing from browser](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/twk0fu/gnome_42_save_as_dialog_box_not_appearing_from/), helped me fix it:

> Go to: chrome://flags -> Preferred Ozone Platform -> "auto".